# How do I verify the integrity of my OSX installation? (Files, versions, and preferences)

Tags: terminal, bash, filesystem, system-settings, defaults

I want to verify the files, and configuration settings for my OSX installation against a known good reference "base".

Assuming I have two identical Macs (hardware), with one being factory installed and up-to-date in patches versus another as-is Mac.. how do I compare the differences between them?  Where do I look?

Although some people may use this answer as forensics, I'm looking more in the sense that I installed a few python libraries and am not sure what I did with them, and want to do some housekeeping.

Terminal commands (`grep, ls`, etc are all welcome).  Lacking an all encompassing solution, I'd appreciate your input on whatever you can contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Mount both volumes on a Mac and drag both drives into a file comparison tool like [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com). It will show file differences as well as hilight files that exist on one folder as opposed to the other folder.

You could also diff a file listing like `ls -laR` or whatever other flags you prefer to see what differences (excepting file metadata and ACL / special flags that either take other `ls` flags or are invisible to a simple file listing.) Some people go so far as to create a listing with md5 or other hashes that checksum the actual contents of files, but that's more appropriate for a security scan / configuration management suite like [munki](http://code.google.com/p/munki/) or [tripwire](http://www.tripwire.com).

Lots of blogs cover that sort of [professional system management like these entries from 318, Inc](http://techjournal.318.com/tag/mac-configuration-management/).